# I'm not able to resume download task in NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have create a demo for downloading a file from the server it is working fine with foreground and background, but when I'm going to resume it, It will giving below Error

I have stcuk here could help me so solved it, I search in internet but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Download file and Pause Downlaod is working fine I have issue to resume it.

```
Task <3AE5BF24-3A4E-4713-8FC2-A0032022C913>.<6> finished with error [-3003] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-3003 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "BackgroundDownloadTask <3AE5BF24-3A4E-4713-8FC2-A0032022C913>.<6>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundDownloadTask <3AE5BF24-3A4E-4713-8FC2-A0032022C913>.<6>}
```

**Here is the final Xcode project**

> [Downlaod xcode project](https://filebin.net/db5c72n96kwg9lxp)

```
#import "NSURLSession+ResumeData.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define IS_IOS10ORLATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 10)

#pragma mark- private

static NSData * correctRequestData(NSData *data) {
    if (!data) {
        return nil;
    }
    // return the same data if it's correct
    if ([NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data] != nil) {
        return data;
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *archive = [[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:nil error:nil] mutableCopy];
    
    if (!archive) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSInteger k = 0;
    id objectss = archive[@"$objects"];
    while ([objectss[1] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%ld",k]] != nil) {
        k += 1;
    }
    NSInteger i = 0;
    while ([archive[@"$objects"][1] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"__nsurlrequest_proto_prop_obj_%ld",i]] != nil) {
        NSMutableArray *arr = archive[@"$objects"];
        NSMutableDictionary *dic = arr[1];
        id obj = [dic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"__nsurlrequest_proto_prop_obj_%ld",i]];
        if (obj) {
            [dic setValue:obj forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%ld",i+k]];
            [dic removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"__nsurlrequest_proto_prop_obj_%ld",i]];
            [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:dic];
            archive[@"$objects"] = arr;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if ([archive[@"$objects"][1] objectForKey:@"__nsurlrequest_proto_props"] != nil) {
        NSMutableArray *arr = archive[@"$objects"];
        NSMutableDictionary *dic = arr[1];
        id obj = [dic objectForKey:@"__nsurlrequest_proto_props"];
        if (obj) {
            [dic setValue:obj forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%ld",i+k]];
            [dic removeObjectForKey:@"__nsurlrequest_proto_props"];
            [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:dic];
            archive[@"$objects"] = arr;
        }
    }
    // Rectify weird "NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey" top key to NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey = "root"
    if ([archive[@"$top"] objectForKey:@"NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey"] != nil) {
        [archive[@"$top"] setObject:archive[@"$top"][@"NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey"] forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey];
        [archive[@"$top"] removeObjectForKey:@"NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey"];
    }
    // Reencode archived object
    NSData *result = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:archive format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:nil];
    return result;
}

static NSMutableDictionary *getResumeDictionary(NSData *data) {
    NSMutableDictionary *iresumeDictionary = nil;
    if (IS_IOS10ORLATER) {
        id root = nil;
        id keyedUnarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
        @try {
            root = [keyedUnarchiver decodeTopLevelObjectForKey:@"NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey" error:nil];
            if (root == nil) {
                root = [keyedUnarchiver decodeTopLevelObjectForKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey error:nil];
            }
        } @catch(NSException *exception) {
            
        }
        [keyedUnarchiver finishDecoding];
        iresumeDictionary = [root mutableCopy];
    }
    
    if (iresumeDictionary == nil) {
        iresumeDictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:nil error:nil];
    }
    return iresumeDictionary;
}

static NSData *correctResumeData(NSData *data) {
    NSString *kResumeCurrentRequest = @"NSURLSessionResumeCurrentRequest";
    NSString *kResumeOriginalRequest = @"NSURLSessionResumeOriginalRequest";
    if (data == nil) {
        return  nil;
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *resumeDictionary = getResumeDictionary(data);
    if (resumeDictionary == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    resumeDictionary[kResumeCurrentRequest] = correctRequestData(resumeDictionary[kResumeCurrentRequest]);
    resumeDictionary[kResumeOriginalRequest] = correctRequestData(resumeDictionary[kResumeOriginalRequest]);
    NSData *result = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:resumeDictionary format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:nil];
    return result;
}

@implementation NSURLSession (ResumeData)

- (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTaskWithCorrectResumeData:(NSData *)resumeData {
    NSString *kResumeCurrentRequest = @"NSURLSessionResumeCurrentRequest";
    NSString *kResumeOriginalRequest = @"NSURLSessionResumeOriginalRequest";
    
    NSData *cData = correctResumeData(resumeData);
    cData = cData ? cData:resumeData;
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [self downloadTaskWithResumeData:cData];
    NSMutableDictionary *resumeDic = getResumeDictionary(cData);
    if (resumeDic) {
        if (task.originalRequest == nil) {
            NSData *originalReqData = resumeDic[kResumeOriginalRequest];
            NSURLRequest *originalRequest = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:originalReqData ];
            if (originalRequest) {
                [task setValue:originalRequest forKey:@"originalRequest"];
            }
        }
        if (task.currentRequest == nil) {
            NSData *currentReqData = resumeDic[kResumeCurrentRequest];
            NSURLRequest *currentRequest = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:currentReqData];
            if (currentRequest) {
                [task setValue:currentRequest forKey:@"currentRequest"];
            }
        }
    }
    return task;
}

@end
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be saving the data somewhere so that you can resume later? Show how you save the partial data and also how you restore it when the app is launched again.

Comment: could you please have a look Xcode project?   https://filebin.net/db5c72n96kwg9lxp

Comment: I did - that is why I made that comment. Nowhere do I see you storing the state of a ongoing download nor restoring it again when the app restarts and I think that is what you need.